# Generating modern js-based rich client from server side?

Tags: javascript, code-organization, generated-code

I am working on a intra-net project, which uses javascript for client side effects/widgets, like tree, grid, dragging. We are thinking about to use jquery/backbone plus some jquery ui.

The problem is, with great flexibility of jquery/backbone, our low experienced developers are almost certained to make code **MESSY**. And I hate that.

To reduce the chance they can make code messy, I am going to build a server-side program to parse xml (those developer will write xml instead of javascript when possible) and generate javascript at runtime. By doing this, I can force restriction on the xml. And xml tends to be less messy.

But before jumping into that, I want to ask is there any similar existing framework? Preferably the javascript generated also make use of model/view/controller pattern.

Or what else can I do to prevent the project from being messy?

ps: I want to educate the developer. But that is a long term job. Not really helpful for current project.

Thank you guys/girls.

---

Alright, a terrible idea I think. So besides training my developers (for long term), what else can I do? Especially in short term because the project is rolling on?

Comment: Whatever framework you write is going to be a nightmare to maintain and or use. If you hire Web Developers and don't let them do Web development you may need to reconsider how you do things. Nobody wants to write XML and you will almost certainly make things more difficult to write.

Comment: I would consider extjs as a js framework which doesn't tend to get messy, instead of your xml based code generation.

Comment: This sounds like an absolutely terrible idea. Expressing logic and control flow in XML would be extremely verbose.

Comment: I agree with you guys. But unfortunetly, 1) to @Deadron, they are java developers, not web developers, and thats why js code are messy.

Comment: 2) to @Amit: we used extjs before, but lots of handler/ajax.request/panel creation config are nested in infinite curly brace ( I blame this to low experience with js of my developers)

Comment: If you have developers who can't write JS to the standard you want, then introduce code reviews and training and raise their JS skills to a level where they can.

Comment: You can try gwt, it will generate client side js and html from server side java code.

Comment: well, @Aldarund beat me to it. Google Web Toolkit is the beast for you. You write java, and out comes JavaScript. Sounds like a perfect fit, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your goal but I think that trying to enforce coding standards in a programmatic way is over-solutionising the problem.  The following steps help to steer you in the right direction though:

1. Use a version control system such as SVN or Git.  Not only does this allow you to pinpoint who is messing up your code and educate them, but it gives you the option to roll back changes that completely break your project.  It shouldn't be seen as a "blaming" mechanism, but is certainly a reliable way to identify the culprit.  You may also find that your developers are less likely to commit code that isn't up to scratch after they realise their work is open to such scrutiny.
2. Documentation - and I don't necessarily mean having a 300 page wiki on how your project is organised and how functions should be written.  But even something as simple as commenting every function will often encourage others to do the same.  The important thing is that the developer sees the standard of work they are expected to deliver in your work.  Developers with potential will take their cues from you.
3. Paired programming - get into the habit of sitting with your developers while they code.  Not 100% of the time, but often enough that you are aware of their strengths and weaknesses.  Teach them the way you want them to code.
4. If all else fails, resort to tools that help developers with their standards, such as the [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) plugin for Visual Studio.  While this is primarily designed for C# usage, it also provides code hints etc. for Javascript that will help inexperienced developers adopt a set of practices that should improve the readability of their code.

I don't think there is any substitute for a good tutor, and providing any sort of automated solution is likely to cause a lot of headaches for you without ever really improving the skills of those you are hoping to teach.